# Настройка visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Инструкция:  Для работы с библиотекой Winsock 2.х в исходный тест программы необходимо включить директиву `#include <winsock2.h>`, а в командной строке линкера указать `ws2_32.lib`. В среде разработки Microsoft Visual Studio для этого достаточно нажать <Alt-F7>, перейти к закладке "Link" и к списку библиотек, перечисленных в строке "Object/Library modules", добавить `ws2_32.lib`, отделив ее от остальных символом пробела.  В 2010-ой студии, перейдя в Linker->Command Line, нельзя отредактировать поле.  Что делать? Как компилить под winsock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

Если не удается в настройки запихнуть, то в начале пропиши:

```
#pragma comment ( lib, "ws2_32.lib" )
```

Эффект тот же, но все же там должен быть способ это в настройки прописать